# Is my LDAP syntax wrong in search filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

This is my first attempt in trying to query our LDAP server for AD info. When I am trying to query the LDAP server here is what I'm trying to retrieve:

I am trying to retrieve all active employees with a countlimit of 500 records whose displayname starts with "sav", has an email address and has a userAccountControl attribute of 512. The problem I'm encountering is that I'm only getting back 8 records total. I should literally be getting back at least 10 records.

I did a separate search on the 2 records that were NOT retrieved in my search and each had an email address and a userAccountControl value of 512.  So I'm not sure why those 2 records were missing.

I'm sure I've done something wrong in my syntax but I cannot find what it is. Any HELP/DIRECTION would be appreciated.  Thank you.

After googling I've defined the SEARCH FILTER as:

```
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname="+displayname+"*"+")(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))";
```

Please see my complete method below:

```
public List&lt;String&gt; getAutocompleteEmpRecordsList(String displayname, LdapContext ctx) {
    List&lt;String&gt; activeEmpAttributes = new ArrayList&lt;String&gt;();
    Attributes attrs = null;
    int count = 0;
    int empEmailAddrLen = 0;
    try {
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setCountLimit(500);          
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attrIDs = {"displayname", "mail", "userAccountControl"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname="+displayname+"*"+")(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))";
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("OU=Standard,OU=Users,DC=xxx,DC=org", searchFilter, constraints);
        if (answer != null) {
            while (answer.hasMore()) {
                attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
                if (attrs.get("displayname") != null) {
                    int empNameLen = attrs.get("displayname").toString().length();
                    activeEmpAttributes.add(attrs.get("displayname").toString().substring(13, empNameLen));
                }
                count++;
                ctx.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }
        System.out.println("activeEmpAttributes: " + activeEmpAttributes);
        System.out.println("count: " + activeEmpAttributes.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return activeEmpAttributes;
}
```

Comment: The syntax looks OK, although you should look into the search() overload that takes seperate searchArgs, so your filter can be `(&(objectClass=user)(displayname={0}*)(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))` where {0} refers to the first searchArg.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing `displayname` attribute and `cn` attribute.

On Windows server you've got a command line tool called LDIDIFDE.EXE which can allow you to test your filter.

```
ldifde -f datas.ldf -d "OU=Standard,OU=THR Users,DC=txhealth,DC=org" -r "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=sav*)(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))"
ldifde -f datas.ldf -d "OU=Standard,OU=THR Users,DC=txhealth,DC=org" -r "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=sav*)(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))"
```

In the User and computer MMC you can also test your filter.

Start User and computer Active-Directory :

[image: User and computer Active-Directory]

Right buton on registered request :

[image: New request]

Choose personalize search, you've got an helper tab for common attributes :

[image: helper tab for common attributes]

You can choose personalized tab for technical attributes

[image: personalized tab for technical attributes]

You can test en copy the resulting LDAP filter (you don't need the double *(&* one is enough):

[image: Resulting LDAP filter]

Comment: Thanks for your time in replying. But I found my problem and posted it above for others who may run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your userAccountControl, displayName, and mail values for the two excluded users?

FWIW the medial search on displayName would run alot faster if you add a tuple index to it.

Comment: Thanks for your time in replying.  But I found my problem and posted it above for others who may run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a free AD tool to view all in AD that I needed and it showed me that the data was not the problem but I was just not hitting all the OU's that I needed because there is NOT just 1 OU where all our users are stored.

Consequently, after googling some more I found a page on the Oracle site regarding LDAP and I changed my LDAPContext to DirContext for my connection to do searches within the directory as well as using this context's REFERRAL and set the value to "follow" to avoid the PartialSearchException.

I thought I'd post my findings just in case some other newbie ran into the same issue.

If you see a downside to the changes I made please let me know. Regards.

Here is my corrected code:

```
public List<String> getAutocompleteEmpRecordsList(String displayname, DirContext ctx) {
    List<String> activeEmpAttributes = new ArrayList<String>();
    Attributes attrs = null;
    int count = 0;
    int empEmailAddrLen = 0;
    try {
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setCountLimit(500); 
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attrIDs = {"displayname", "mail", "userAccountControl"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname="+displayname.trim()+"*"+")(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512))";
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=xxx,DC=org", searchFilter, constraints);
        if (answer != null) {
            while (answer.hasMore()) {
                attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
                if (attrs.get("displayname") != null) {
                    int empNameLen = attrs.get("displayname").toString().length();
                    activeEmpAttributes.add(attrs.get("displayname").toString().substring(13, empNameLen));
                }
                count++;
                ctx.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }
        System.out.println("activeEmpAttributes: " + activeEmpAttributes);
        System.out.println("count: " + activeEmpAttributes.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return activeEmpAttributes;
}
```

Thanks anyway.